# How to connect postgres with ruby on remote machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am on remote machine with CentOS with an IP and my postgres is on different IP. 
I want to access postgres with my rails server.  I edited the database.yml file and installed gem pg and included host IP in database.yml file.. But I am unable to run the rake db:migrate and rails server.. It shows PG ERROR as below.Help me to solve this . I am trying to connect to server from past 4 days..but I cant...
when i run db:migrate it show sthe following error.

```
[root@vdimc04 My_Postgres]# rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

   **my database.yml file**
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  password: password
  host: 192.168.1.101
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara_test
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
password: password


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara_production
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
password: password
```

Comment: @vijikumar hey did you made any changes????

Comment: when i run rake db:migrate it shows as : 
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 1..

How can i get rid of this???????

Comment: @SeanHill I have edited my problem and added my error while i run db:migrate and my database.yml file also>>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this error:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

You need to check the permissions set in the `pg_hba.conf` file on the remote server.  Likely, you do not allow remote connections to connect to the server.  It should look something like this, for example:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
# Remote connections
host    your_db     your_user   (Client IP ADDR)      md5
```

You can use `0.0.0.0/0`, but that will allow connections from any host.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly looks for PostgreSQL on the local machine:

> Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Your`database.yml` should comtain something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: very_Secure12/
  host: 224.13.156.78
  port: 5432
```

You can use an IP or a hostname like `dbserver.myvompany.com` in the `host` line.  And it should not contain a line which starts with `socket`.  And, finally, PostgreSQL must accept connections from this server.

Comment: @dezso..Thank u for answering me.. I have edited as you showed..But when i run rake db:migrate it shows (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 1


 my database name is: db_pchamara so i edited the file as below: 

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  database: db_pchamara
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  password: password
  host: 192.168.1.101
  port: 5432

Comment: @PavanKumar So, after your change, is it working?  Thanks for this comment anyway, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: no.. it is not working..when i run rake db:migrate it shows error that 
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 1..........

what does this mean??? is it necessary to run this rake db:migrate??

Comment: i edited my roblem and added my database.yml file and also added error while i run rake db:migrate... Please go through that once..

Comment: Is there the line of `port` or not?